# equation align ( for each t)

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

I'm writing equations that have different length in Latex , I would like to make the end of each equation ( for each t) to be in the same place in each equation. How can I do that?[image: example]

Comment: Does this form part of a bigger equation and you're only specifying the conditions of the variables? If so, can you provide that additional context? Also, you should consider providing the code for what you've shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may want to use array in this case, for example

```
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{ll}
{q_\mathrm{t}^\mathrm{p}\geq0} & {\forall p\in\mathcal{P}\hspace{2mm}\forall t} \\
{R_\mathrm{t}^\mathrm{s}\geq0} & {\forall t}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

The `{lr}` behind the `\begin{array}` represent that the first column do left-justify and the second column do left-justify, if you want to have right-justify, use letter `r`.

Here's the result:

[image]

Also, you can add as many `\qquad` as you want if you create another column, like this:

```
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{lcl}
{q_\mathrm{t}^\mathrm{p}\geq0} & {\qquad\qquad} & {\forall p\in\mathcal{P}\hspace{2mm}\forall t} \\
{R_\mathrm{t}^\mathrm{s}\geq0} & {\qquad\qquad} & {\forall t}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This might look a little nicer with the first column being set right-aligned, since the zeros are the same width; that would line up the signs of relation.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I didn't notice the lower case and upper case problem. Usually when I am doing such things myself, I would add the big `{` or `}` to make it looks nicer.

Answer (score 4):

This is very simply obtained with `alignat`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
 q_\mathrm{t}^\mathrm{p} & \geq 0 & \qquad & \forall p\in\mathcal{P}\hspace{2mm} & \enspace & \forall t\\
 R_\mathrm{t}^\mathrm{s} & \geq 0 & & & & \forall t
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hope you like it!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
 q_\mathrm{t}^\mathrm{p}\geq0 \qquad \forall p\in\mathcal{P}\hspace{2mm}\forall t&\\
 R_\mathrm{t}^\mathrm{s}\geq0 \qquad \forall t&
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example]